# Joining lists and create dynamic columns

Tags: 2010, caml, ootb, joined-view

I have 3 lists A, B and C in the same site and i have to make a **View** joining them and generate few dynamic columns:

**Columns of A:** Title (Indexed), Util(number)

**Columns of B:** Title, Title_A (Lookup), Date (Date), Used(number) - no. of util used

**Columns of C:** Title, Title_A (Lookup)

For a view i can easily join all the rows and see the entries, but the **conditions are**:

1. A join B should bring only latest values in B for A
2. If B has no values for A then it should bring join with "Used" value as 0 and "Date" value as "01/01/0001" (Default .NET Date value)

**Dynamic Columns**: 

Blank **columns per row** with background color or image depending upon the following condition

1. **Util Status:** If "Used"(List B) > "Util"(List A) --> "red" else "green"
2. **C_Entry:** If List C has any entry for A --> "green" else "red"
3. **Last Date:** If latest "Date" after Join > 7 days old --> "red" else "green"
4. **Link:** Image Button with links to "**Linked.aspx?Parameter=["ID"(List A)]**" page

How can i achieve this with best performance?

**Note:** This view can contain thousands of elements.
**Restrictions:** I cannot use rest services or CSOM as the services are not accessible to users but can use server side scripting (if required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other option will be to use designer workflow.

Add the columns you require in List A and whenever any item get added/updated in List B or List C, use a workflow to update the values in List A as per your requirement. For dynamic columns use calculated columns.

Comment: Thank you. I was also thinking of the same thing but the only thing i was worried about was the massive amount of data i will have to store per list item and then the enormous amount of cases i will have to handle with the event receiver. But i guess this would work fine. Anyway is there any case in which i can save the space consumed by storage of redundant data in LIst A from B and C?